# AccountContactRelation and child custom objects. Sharing behavior

Tags: community, sharing, apex-sharing, accountcontactrelation, parent-to-child

I'm using AccountContactRelation to give access to some accounts to my community users.
It's working great in this regard.

but the thing is, i got a custom "Contrat" object that is a child of account (Master-detail) and it seems the access given by the accountContactRelation is not sharing with the community user in this case.

Here is the example:
My contact (Also community user) has 2 related account, one is direct (DC superTest) one is not direct (DC GARAGE MIDAS)
[image]

If I connect to my community and go to a list view of Account I see both of them which is great.
But when I go to my standard listview of Custom "Contrat" Object I got the following:
[image]

Here is a good time to mention that we have ONE contract per account. So i should see 2.
My sharings are set to private on the accounts and my Custom "Contrat" object is "Controled by parent and can not be changed.

I tried to create an accountShare using apex and it give me the visibility on the contract associated with the "DC GARAGE MIDAS" Account. (see below is after sharing using apex).

[image]

So I can sort of resolve my problem using apex sharing but I wonder why it is not working in a native way with AccountContactRelation. Is it not creating a sharing? Why? What does it do? (didn't find a lot on the docs) For me It absolutly should. Am I missing something? If anyone with a knowledge on this object could enlighten me i'll be very happy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your community user have access to the Contract record because that user is created based on the Account/Contact which shares access to it.
Indirect relationship does not give that access without any additional configuration (well it's called indirect relationship for a reason -> indirect relationship is a normal Detail side of the Account-Contact Master Detail. And sharing is not give to a sibling Detail which in your case Contract is).

You are not limited to the Apex though, it can be configured using Sharing Sets. You can set proper sharing based on the Contact.RelatedAccount there.

Comment: Thanks i figured out some moments after the question but your answer confirm that.
I might have to aks a new question but it seems on the sharing set I can only have one rule per objet and I already use one.